# How to return an included file in PHP without using a return

Tags: php, html, json, templates

I am trying to turn an existing website in an API, in order to do that I need to return some content as HTML inside a JSON. The problem I am having is that I can't find a way to make templating work.

I tried to do this

```
class TestController
{
    public function get() {
    $adapter = new Adapter();

    $data = 'some data';
    $html = include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'template.php';

    $result = [
        'html' => $html
    ];

    return json_encode($result);
}

template.php:
<div>
    <br/><?= $data ?><br/>
</div>
```

but it is returning the HTML alongside the JSON and of course html = 1 because include returns 1 on success, like this:

```
<div>
    <br/>some data<br/>
</div>
{'html':1}
```

Is there a way for me to get the content from the included file without using a return statement inside the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that using include essentially treats your template.php file as a single giant "echo" because there is no value returned inside template.php

You *could* change the template.php file to return a HTML string, and it would achieve what you want, but this is a nightmare to look at and manage.

```
return '<div>
<br/>' . $data . '<br/>
</div>';
```

An alternative, is to "capture" the output of the included file. Its a lot nicer on your template.php file and achieves the same thing. The output buffer functions essentially capture any information "echoed" - you need to be careful using this and the placement of your session_start however as it can catch you off guard depending on how your application is bootstrapped.

This is done by using three ob_ functions the main one being ob_get_contents which will be the contents of template.php in the example below.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

```
ob_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'template.php';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

This was your template files stay nice and clean, and the contents are all captured for returning in your json format.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **ob_start** like this

```
ob_start();
include 'path_to_your_file.php';
$result= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```